# Javascript and django app / boilerplate integration

Tags: javascript, django, boilerplate

I'm writting a Django app, combined with a boilerplate template. 
I have a table with checkboxes and I'm trying to implement a select all checkbox using javascript but is not working

Following this recomendation [django checkbox select all by jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554872/django-checkbox-select-all-by-jquery?rq=1)  I put  in  main.js

```
$("#selectAll").live('change',function() {
  $(".checkbox_delete:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

I also tried to put it directly on index.html

On my index.html y wrote

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="selectAll"  />
<label for="selectAll"> Select</label>

 {% for event in latest_events_list %}
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_delete" name="event" id="event.id"
         value="{{ event.id }}"  />
{% endfor %}
```

The page is correctly displayed but the javascript doesnt work

The boilerplate generates the link to js files.  In the header appears

```
<script src="/static/js/dh5bp/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

And before closing the body tag :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write ('<script     src="/static/js/dh5bp/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 <script src="/static/js/dh5bp/plugins.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

All the js files are correctly linked, I can follow them

I have no experience with js., so I dont know if I'm missing something.

EDIT:

I installed firebug on both browsers.  On firefox it warned me that

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function    

$("#selectAll").live('change',function() {
```

so i changed the code for

```
$(function(){
    $("#selectAll").change(function() {
    $(".checkbox_delete:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
 });
```

Now it works just the first time i load the page, but if i "select all" and "unselect all" I cant "select all" them again

Comment: Check all js files are included in your page using firebug. You can post some code for us to help you.

Comment: I checked and are all included,  main.js,  plugins.js, nodernizr and jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it works,

the problem is the attr()

According to this post  [jquery select all checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880313/jquery-select-all-checkboxes?rq=1)

> in jQuery 1.6 and above, prop() should be used for "checked" status instead of attr() with true or false being passed

Finally the working code was

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {
   $(".checkbox_delete:checkbox").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".checkbox_delete:checkbox").attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked));
```

Try with this

Comment: '$(".checkbox_delete").attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked));' This have to work.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong in your code that I can find is the following:

```
$(".checkbox_delete:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
```

this should be

```
$(".checkbox_delete[type="checkbox"]").attr('checked', this.checked);
```

**NOTE**

`[type="checkbox"]` won't be needed if you have good classnames and don't use the `.checkbox_delete` on radio's etc.

Your original selector was not valid. You would have gotten errors logged into your console.

In firefox the shortcut for this is `F12`, If you don't have firebug for FF / Chrome installed, I'd recommend you do so as it is an extremely good way of checking for JS errors, which usually ends in solving them as well.

Comment: I 'll edit my question with more details , obtained after your comment

Comment: this piece  `$(".checkbox_delete[type="checkbox"]") `   throw me an error, there is some missing symbol?

Comment: use single quotes for checkbox. '$(".checkbox_delete[type='checkbox']")'

Comment: `.live();` is also deprecated, it's best to just bind a `.click();` handler that checks wether the checkbox was ticked and from there ticks all the other checkboxes. jquery updates frequently and all the deprecated functions can be found in their changelog.